# Azure ASP.NET Web App - Sign into B2C Protected REST API?

Tags: asp.net, azure, rest, azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone have any good samples on how to connect to a b2c authenticated rest API in a web app?

I understand this is seems an obvious thing to search and find, but ive been hunting around microsoft pages for an hour, and keep getting lead to:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/master/

which i think is completely outdated and leads to an endless hole of errors no matter what i do and what guides/questions i search and follow.

After updating target framework and all nuget, i end up with logger errors, and trying to bypass those i just get

HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of testing, but I may have finally found the updated solution:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C